# How can I share non-internet printer using PC that is USB connected to the printer?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printing, printer

How can I share a non-internet printer using a PC that is connected to the printer via USB?

I have [this printer (Brother HL-L2310D)](https://support.brother.com/g/b/producttop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=hll2310d_us_eu_as):

[image: Brother HL-L2310D]

I want to share my printer with devices connected to my local network for example my iPhone, iPad, MacBook.

I have a windows 10 PC that is connected to the printer and is always on 24/7. So I was wondering if I can make this PC a print server for my printing requests.

In other words, Can I share my non-internet printer? Or should I get one that supports internet?

Comment: I’ve Windows 10 professional

Comment: You can also use a USB to ethernet convertor [Explained here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/Can-you-use-a-usb-to-ethernet-adapter-to-set-up-one-printer/td-p/7096603) if you dont want to leave your PC on

Comment: Or you can simply [share the printer on the network](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/share-your-network-printer-c9a152b5-59f3-b6f3-c99f-f39e5bf664c3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on the specific devices/OS you want to print from and the specific device/OS on the 24/7 PC.

Sharing a printer is different and depends on the server OS (Linux, Windwos, Apple, etc.). Connecting **to** the shared printer depends on the server protocol used for sharing and if the device (the client) trying to connect to the server supports the protocol.

Unfortunately, there is no general answer here, but there are loads of step-by-step instructions on the internet. Just try "sharing printer via Windows/Linux/etc." you should get usable results pretty quickly.

The advantage of an "internet printer" is that it usually it has more advanced sharing options. E.g. you can just send a file via email to the printer (assuming that's supported by the printer). There are various options here depending on the printer you choose.

Answer (score 2):

You can leave your computer on 24x7 and that should work.

Another and possibly as good or better approach is a USB Print Server.

[Examples of Print Servers](https://www.newegg.ca/Network-Print-Servers/SubCategory/ID-387)

Print Servers are good because they do not require an always on computer. They sit on the network and any device on your network can use them.

I keep my own printer on the Network and it works best.

If you get a new printer, even if Internet capable, get with a LAN connection as well. My HP printer can do both.

On LAN printers each device needs a printer driver

Comment: `How can I share` .. this answer doesn't even touch Mr. John! :)  So simply leaving my computer turned on will make my printer shared on the network? :^P

Comment: I added about each device needing a driver. Very common so I took it for granted.  But I did add the need

Comment: I didn't -1 you btw.  People already have drivers for their printers.  I was talking about [file and printer sharing](https://www.dummies.com/article/technology/information-technology/networking/general-networking/how-to-enable-file-and-printer-sharing-windows-7-and-8-164955/).